# Cannot launch node of type [motoman_driver/robot_state]: cannot locate node of type [robot_state] in package [motoman_driver]

Tags: ros, nodes, roslauch, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We are currently working on establishing connection with a Yaskawa HC10DT robot using ROS Industrial. We have all the packages listed here https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman and all ROS Industrial packages. However, when we want to follow the instructions listed here http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/Usage, we get the error seen in the attached picture. We would be thankful if someone could help us with this issue.

We are using Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) and ROS Melodic (version: 1.14.13).

Build workspace:

```
~$ source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
~$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
~$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
~$ catkin_make
~$ catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3
~$ source devel/setup.bash
```

Download Packages (packages we downloaded from https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman):

```
~$ cd $HOME/catkin_ws/src
~$ git clone -b melodic-devel https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman.git src/motoman
~$ rosdep update
~$ rosdep install --from-paths src/ --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic
~$ catkin build
~$ source $HOME/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

When trying to run this instruction (note: real robot IP address is not displayed below):

```
~$ source /home/student/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
# First we tried this command
~$ roslaunch motoman_driver robot_interface_streaming_yrc1000.launch robot_ip:=XX.XXX.XX.XX
# Second we tried this command
~$ roslaunch motoman_hc10_support robot_interface_streaming_hc10dt.launch robot_ip:=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX controller:=yrc1000
```

We obtained the following error:

```
... logging to /home/student/.ros/log/18c3894e-d6be-11ec-92d2-3417ebabbff9/roslaunch-student-OptiPlex-9020-5457.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://student-OptiPlex-9020:39861/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /io_relay/port: 50242
 * /robot_ip_address: XX.XXX.XX.XX
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.13

NODES
  /
    io_relay (motoman_driver/io_relay)
    joint_state (motoman_driver/robot_state)
    joint_trajectory_action (industrial_robot_client/joint_trajectory_action)
    motion_streaming_interface (motoman_driver/motion_streaming_interface)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [motoman_driver/robot_state]: Cannot locate node of type [robot_state] in package [motoman_driver]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [motoman_driver/motion_streaming_interface]: Cannot locate node of type [motion_streaming_interface] in package [motoman_driver]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [motoman_driver/io_relay]: Cannot locate node of type [io_relay] in package [motoman_driver]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
process[joint_trajectory_action-4]: started with pid [5472]
[ WARN] [1652887326.581429246]: Unable to find user-specified joint names in 'controller_joint_names'
[ WARN] [1652887326.582446633]: Unable to find URDF joint names in 'robot_description'
[ERROR] [1652887326.582477290]: Cannot find user-specified joint names. Tried ROS parameter 'controller_joint_names' and the URDF in 'robot_description'.
[ERROR] [1652887326.582503122]: Failed to initialize joint_names.
[ WARN] [1652887327.586912877]: Trajectory state not received for 1.000000 seconds
```

In order to solve the issue above, we performed the following actions:

```
~$ cd $HOME/catkin_ws
~$ sudo pip install empy
~$ catkin_make
```

The packages were then installed and built successfully without any errors.

This seems to have solved the previous problem that originated this post. However, now we are getting a new error when running the following commands:

```
~$ roslaunch motoman_hc10_support robot_interface_streaming_hc10dt.launch robot_ip:=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX controller:=yrc1000
```

Output when running the command above:

```
... logging to /home/student/.ros/log/c9d66382-d862-11ec-b02f-3417ebabbff9/roslaunch-student-OptiPlex-9020-9469.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://student-OptiPlex-9020:39413/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /io_relay/port: 50242
 * /robot_ip_address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.13

NODES
  /
    io_relay (motoman_driver/io_relay)
    joint_state (motoman_driver/robot_state)
    joint_trajectory_action (industrial_robot_client/joint_trajectory_action)
    motion_streaming_interface (motoman_driver/motion_streaming_interface)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[joint_state-1]: started with pid [9484]
process[motion_streaming_interface-2]: started with pid [9485]
process[io_relay-3]: started with pid [9491]
process[joint_trajectory_action-4]: started with pid [9496]
[ WARN] [1653072702.361150330]: Unable to read velocity limits from 'robot_description' param.  Velocity validation disabled.
[ WARN] [1653072702.373243881]: Tried to connect when socket already in connected state

^C[joint_trajectory_action-4] killing on exit
[io_relay-3] killing on exit
[motion_streaming_interface-2] killing on exit
[joint_state-1] killing on exit
[ERROR] [1653072715.708198060]: Socket select function failed, rc: -1. Error: 'Interrupted system call' (errno: 4)
motion_streaming_interface: /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:111: boost::mutex::~mutex(): Assertion `!res' failed.
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Following the steps and suggestions from the last comment, the following steps were performed.

Correction from your point 3 (comments on the latest edit):
We actually used:

```
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman.git src/motoman
```

Uninstall empy

```
sudo pip uninstall empy
```

Remove build and devel folders from catkin_ws

```
cd $HOME/catkin_ws
rm -rf build devel
```

Rebuild catkin_ws using catkin_tools

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
catkin build
```

Output

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /opt/ros/melodic
Workspace:                   /home/student/catkin_ws
------------------------------------------------------------
Build Space:        [exists] /home/student/catkin_ws/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/student/catkin_ws/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/student/catkin_ws/install
Log Space:         [missing] /home/student/catkin_ws/logs
Source Space:       [exists] /home/student/catkin_ws/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.

NOTE: Forcing CMake to run for each package.
------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '37' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                                         
[build] Updating package table.                                                                     
Starting  >>> catkin_tools_prebuild                                                                 
Finished  <<< catkin_tools_prebuild                       [ 2.0 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_msgs                                                                          
Starting  >>> motoman_resources                                                                     
Finished  <<< motoman_resources                           [ 1.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_motopos_d500_support                                                          
Finished  <<< motoman_msgs                                [ 4.0 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_driver                                                                        
Finished  <<< motoman_motopos_d500_support                [ 2.4 seconds ]                           
Finished  <<< motoman_driver                              [ 34.0 seconds ]                          
Starting  >>> motoman_ar2010_support                                                                
Starting  >>> motoman_es_support                                                                    
Starting  >>> motoman_gp110_support                                                                 
Starting  >>> motoman_gp12_support                                                                  
Starting  >>> motoman_gp180_support                                                                 
Starting  >>> motoman_gp200r_support                                                                
Starting  >>> motoman_gp25_support                                                                  
Starting  >>> motoman_gp4_support                                                                   
Finished  <<< motoman_gp12_support                        [ 2.5 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_gp50_support                                                                  
Finished  <<< motoman_gp25_support                        [ 2.6 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_gp7_support                                                                   
Finished  <<< motoman_gp4_support                         [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_gp88_support                                                                  
Finished  <<< motoman_es_support                          [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_gp8_support                                                                   
Finished  <<< motoman_gp110_support                       [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_hc10_support                                                                  
Finished  <<< motoman_ar2010_support                      [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_hc20_support                                                                  
Finished  <<< motoman_gp200r_support                      [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_ma2010_support                                                                
Finished  <<< motoman_gp180_support                       [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_mh12_support                                                                  
Finished  <<< motoman_gp50_support                        [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_mh50_support                                                                  
Finished  <<< motoman_gp7_support                         [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_mh5_support                                                                   
Finished  <<< motoman_gp88_support                        [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_motomini_support                                                              
Finished  <<< motoman_gp8_support                         [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_ms210_support                                                                 
Finished  <<< motoman_hc10_support                        [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_sda10f_support                                                                
Finished  <<< motoman_hc20_support                        [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_sia10d_support                                                                
Finished  <<< motoman_ma2010_support                      [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_sia10f_support                                                                
Finished  <<< motoman_mh12_support                        [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_sia20d_support                                                                
Finished  <<< motoman_mh50_support                        [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_sia30d_support                                                                
Finished  <<< motoman_mh5_support                         [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_sia50_support                                                                 
Finished  <<< motoman_motomini_support                    [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_sia5d_support                                                                 
Finished  <<< motoman_ms210_support                       [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_mh110_support                                                                 
Finished  <<< motoman_sda10f_support                      [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_ma2010_moveit_config                                                          
Finished  <<< motoman_sia10d_support                      [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_ms210_moveit_config                                                           
Finished  <<< motoman_sia10f_support                      [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_sda10f_moveit_config                                                          
Finished  <<< motoman_sia20d_support                      [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Starting  >>> motoman_sia20d_moveit_config                                                          
Finished  <<< motoman_sia30d_support                      [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Finished  <<< motoman_sia50_support                       [ 2.8 seconds ]                           
Finished  <<< motoman_sia5d_support                       [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Finished  <<< motoman_mh110_support                       [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Finished  <<< motoman_ma2010_moveit_config                [ 2.7 seconds ]                           
Finished  <<< motoman_ms210_moveit_config                 [ 2.6 seconds ]                           
Finished  <<< motoman_sda10f_moveit_config                [ 2.6 seconds ]                           
Finished  <<< motoman_sia20d_moveit_config                [ 2.5 seconds ]                           
[build] Summary: All 37 packages succeeded!                                                         
[build]   Ignored:   1 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.                                    
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                                          
[build]   Abandoned: None.                                                                          
[build]   Failed:    None.                                                                          
[build] Runtime: 51.5 seconds total.                                                                
[build] Note: Workspace packages have changed, please re-source setup files to use them.
```

Resource setup files

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

We then proceeded with

```
roslaunch --screen motoman_hc10_support robot_interface_streaming_hc10dt.launch robot_ip:=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX controller:=yrc1000
```

The following output was obtained:

```
... logging to /home/student/.ros/log/d43728f2-db7d-11ec-8bd8-3417ebabbff9/roslaunch-student-OptiPlex-9020-3761.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://student-OptiPlex-9020:34575/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /controller_joint_names: ['joint_1_s', 'jo...
 * /io_relay/port: 50242
 * /robot_ip_address: 10.139.0.16
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.13

NODES
  /
    io_relay (motoman_driver/io_relay)
    joint_state (motoman_driver/robot_state)
    joint_trajectory_action (industrial_robot_client/joint_trajectory_action)
    motion_streaming_interface (motoman_driver/motion_streaming_interface)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3772]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to d43728f2-db7d-11ec-8bd8-3417ebabbff9
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3783]
started core service [/rosout]
process[joint_state-2]: started with pid [3786]
process[motion_streaming_interface-3]: started with pid [3787]
process[io_relay-4]: started with pid [3788]
process[joint_trajectory_action-5]: started with pid [3793]
[ INFO] [1653409402.849467082]: Connected to server
[ INFO] [1653409402.879684294]: Adding joint_1_s to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.881017625]: Added message handler for message type: 0
[ INFO] [1653409402.882002701]: Joint Trajectory Interface connecting to IP address: '10.139.0.16:50240'
[ INFO] [1653409402.882596259]: Adding joint_2_l to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.882635739]: Adding joint_3_u to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.882660910]: Adding joint_4_r to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.882684031]: Adding joint_5_b to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.882705962]: Adding joint_6_t to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.882745859]: Found user-specified joint names in 'controller_joint_names': [joint_1_s, joint_2_l, joint_3_u, joint_4_r, joint_5_b, joint_6_t]
[ INFO] [1653409402.882775778]: Filtered joint names to 6 joints
[ INFO] [1653409402.885345596]: Robot state connecting to IP address: '10.139.0.16:50241'
[ INFO] [1653409402.887234622]: Failed to find 'topic_list' parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.887280366]: Expecting/assuming single motion-group controller configuration
[ INFO] [1653409402.887482381]: Failed to find 'topic_list' parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.887519866]: Expecting/assuming single motion-group controller configuration
[ INFO] [1653409402.890519158]: Adding joint_1_s to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.890557937]: Adding joint_2_l to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.890580636]: Adding joint_3_u to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.890595212]: Adding joint_4_r to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.890608001]: Adding joint_5_b to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.890625271]: Adding joint_6_t to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.890672647]: Found user-specified joint names in 'controller_joint_names': [joint_1_s, joint_2_l, joint_3_u, joint_4_r, joint_5_b, joint_6_t]
[ INFO] [1653409402.890702125]: MotomanJointTrajectoryStreamer: init
[ INFO] [1653409402.890727046]: JointTrajectoryStreamer: init
[ INFO] [1653409402.890902790]: Adding joint_1_s to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.890940895]: Adding joint_2_l to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.890970747]: Adding joint_3_u to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.891000909]: Adding joint_4_r to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.891024532]: Adding joint_5_b to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.891050577]: Adding joint_6_t to list parameter
[ INFO] [1653409402.891089289]: Found user-specified joint names in 'controller_joint_names': [joint_1_s, joint_2_l, joint_3_u, joint_4_r, joint_5_b, joint_6_t]
[ INFO] [1653409402.891316776]: Connected to server
[ INFO] [1653409402.891563721]: Connected to server
[ INFO] [1653409402.891609820]: Initializing message manager with default comms fault handler
[ INFO] [1653409402.891649009]: Default communications fault handler successfully initialized
[ INFO] [1653409402.891690651]: Initializing message manager
[ INFO] [1653409402.891726964]: Added message handler for message type: 1
[ WARN] [1653409402.892269154]: Unable to read velocity limits from 'robot_description' param.  Velocity validation disabled.
[ INFO] [1653409402.897182561]: Added message handler for message type: 10
[ INFO] [1653409402.897772343]: Added message handler for message type: 15
[ INFO] [1653409402.902698120]: Entering message manager spin loop
[ INFO] [1653409402.908912821]: Unlocking mutex
[ INFO] [1653409402.908969169]: Starting Motoman joint trajectory streamer thread
[ INFO] [1653409402.914084775]: Connecting to robot motion server
[ WARN] [1653409402.914120742]: Tried to connect when socket already in connected state
```

We used the following command to obtain the joint states:

```
rostopic echo -c /joint_states
```

Output:

```
header: 
  seq: 3706
  stamp: 
    secs: 1653409502
    nsecs: 369215072
  frame_id: ''
name: [joint_1_s, joint_2_l, joint_3_u, joint_4_r, joint_5_b, joint_6_t]
position: [2.391390800476074, 0.09812847524881363, 1.4320321083068848, 0.03563644737005234, -1.3118761777877808, -0.02791845239698887]
velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
effort: []
---
```

Following the instructions listed above, we were able to establish connection with the robot.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400830/cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bmotoman_driver/robot_state%5D:-cannot-locate-node-of-type-%5Brobot_state%5D-in-package-%5Bmotoman_driver%5D/) by [GMG](https://answers.ros.org/users/105244/gmg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-19**:
Please update your post (use the `edit` button/link below it) with the steps you used to setup and build your workspace (ie: `/home/student/catkin_ws`). How did you download the packages? Where did you get them? Which commands did you run? And in which order? What was their output? etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-19**:
Additionally:

> We are currently working on establishing connection with a Yaskawa HC10DT robot

Once you get the build issues sorted out, please don't use `motoman_driver robot_interface_streaming_yrc1000.launch` directly when you have a supported robot (in your case the HC10DT).

Use the following command instead:

```
roslaunch motoman_hc10_support robot_interface_streaming_hc10dt.launch robot_ip:=XX.XXX.XX.XX controller:=yrc1000
```

I've updated the [Usage tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/Usage) to include more relevant information.

**Comment by [GMG](https://answers.ros.org/users/105244/gmg/) on 2022-05-20**:
Thank you for your feedback and help. The post has been updated with the requested information, I hope this will help you get a better understanding on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few things I notice in your edit:

1. your initial build of your empty workspace tries to override the version of Python used by `catkin_make`. Please be aware that Melodic targets Python 2. If you want to use Python 3, you *must* build ROS Melodic from source in its entirety, and you must build it all with Python 3. With what you show here, you now have a regular Melodic, Python 2 install, mixed with a workspace which tries to use Python 3. I'm pretty sure your problem was/is caused by this, as missing `empy` is one of the symptoms of this.

   I would actually recommend you either do *not* use Melodic with Python 3, or switch to ROS Noetic, which supports Python 3.8 natively. `motoman_driver` also works on Noetic.
2. you are mixing using `catkin_make` with `catkin_tools` (ie: `catkin build`). Try not to do that. Stick with `catkin_tools`
3. there is no `melodic-devel` branch in `ros-industrial/motoman`, so `git clone -b melodic-devel ...` won't work
4. having to `sudo pip install ...` something is not good, and should not be needed for a default install of ROS on Ubuntu `18.04`. See my point 1.
5. as the updated Usage tutorial states: do not start `robot_interface_streaming_yrc1000.launch` directly if a suitable robot support package exists. And you have a HC10, which has `motoman_hc10_support`. Use the `.launch` files in that package.
6. the two warnings you show in the final `roslaunch` output are not problematic. If that's all you see then the driver seems to work and have successfully connected.

Having written that, my advice would be:

1. if you're just starting with ROS, do not try to use Python 3 with ROS Melodic. Stick to Python 2, or upgrade to Ubuntu Focal (`20.04`) and ROS Noetic.
2. use `catkin_tools` to build your workspace, always. In fact, you don't need the initial build of an empty workspace, it serves no purpose.
3. undo the `sudo pip install empy`, it should already be installed, but probably for the system-default Python 2 interpreter. If you've made Python 3 the default on your system, `pip` would install packages for *that* interpreter, but all ROS Melodic `apt` packages will still install for Python 2. There is no way to change this, so you'll keep running into this problem. See [Should we warn (new) users about difficulties with Python 3 and alternative Python interpreters?](https://discourse.ros.org/t/should-we-warn-new-users-about-difficulties-with-python-3-and-alternative-python-interpreters/3874) for a discussion about this.

It's certainly possible to use Python 3 with Melodic, but you have to take care to do it everywhere, and it's more involved than just `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3`. See [Build your package using Python 3](http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3/BuildUsingPython3).

Finally: to make sure things work as they are intended, delete your current workspace (or at least the `$HOME/catkin_ws/build` and `$HOME/catkin_ws/devel` folders inside it), and build with just `catkin_tools`, so:

```
cd $HOME/catkin_ws
rm -rf build devel
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
catkin build
source devel/setup.bash
```

at this point you should be able to (note the extra `--screen` option there):

```
roslaunch --screen motoman_hc10_support robot_interface_streaming_hc10dt.launch robot_ip:=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX controller:=yrc1000
```

You will likely still see the two warnings, among other output you didn't see before, but things should now be working.

If they aren't, append all output from `roslaunch` to your starting post and explain how you started things.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GMG](https://answers.ros.org/users/105244/gmg/) on 2022-05-24**:
Hello,

By following your instructions and suggestions we were finally able to establish connection with the robot. I have edited my post and included the steps done in order to connect with the robot.

Thank you very much for all your help!